# Array específico de Strings em PHP é possível?

Tags: php, php-7

Bom, tenho o código abaixo que deveria funcionar mas dá erro:

```
function teste( string... $_array ) : array {

    //FINS DE TESTE

    return $_array;

}

print_r (   teste ( ["teste","2"] ) );
```

Se eu fizer apenas

```
 function teste( array $_array ) : array {

        //FINS DE TESTE

        return $_array;

    }
```

funciona!

Mas eu gostaria de *especificar* que o **array** é de **strings** apenas.

Como fazer isso em PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Até o PHP 7 não havia como especificar o tipo do *array*, eu também queria que pudesse. Entretanto, não sei se em versões recentes tal recurso foi acrescentado.

Mas, o seu primeiro código funciona, apenas acrescentando o `...` no array:

```
// Inalterado
function teste( string... $_array ) : array {
    return $_array;
}

// Acrescentado o `...` antes da array
print_r(teste( ...["teste","2"]));
```

O `...["teste","2"]` fará com que cada item se torne um valor.

Comment: Eu realmente queria que desse para especificar o tipo. Principalmente para poder fazer alguma coisa como: `function() : array[array, bool] {}`, dessa forma especificando que a função retorna uma array onde o primeiro é outra array e o segundo o valor booleano, que seria um sinal erro.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in /var/www/html/gasmuriae.com.br/web/gceu/teste.php on line 7

Comment: linha 7 é:  function teste( string... $_array ) : array {

Comment: @CarlosRocha, isso funciona normalmente em http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8f099274ab7cbded7c4348e8f963bff5d9521b1b (PHP 7.2).

Comment: obrigado. vamos torcer para que melhorem isso pois ...["teste","2"] é ma vergonha para o PHP 7.