# PHP 7 tipado e diferença entre os números de argumentos e parâmetros

Tags: php, php-7

Lendo em:

https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mi

descobri o seguinte *exemplo*:

```
function arraysSum(array ...$arrays): array
{
    return array_map(function(array $array): int {
        return array_sum($array);
    }, $arrays);
}

print_r(arraysSum([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]));
```

Mas percebam que `arraysSum` na sua definição possui apenas 1 **argumento**;

```
arraysSum(array ...$arrays)
```

Mas na chamada são passados 3 **argumentos**

```
arraysSum([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9])
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Digamos que eu precise definir um segundo argumento para esse função como abaixo.

```
function arraysSum(array ...$arrays, int numero): array
{
    return array_map(function(array $array): int {
        return array_sum($array);
    }, $arrays);
}

$numero = 125;
print_r(arraysSum([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]), $numero);
```

Isso vai gerar um erro.

O que fazer para usar linguagem tipada nesses casos sabendo que todos os parâmetro passados na função serão somados?

Parece que existe uma contradição entre o número de parâmetros da função e o número de argumentos passados na chamada.

Eu não estou entendendo muito bem isso!

Meu objetivo é fazer algo como:

```
<?php

function teste( string... $_array, string a ) : array {

    return array_push($_array, a);

}

print_r( teste (...["teste","2"], "adicionado") );
```

mas sem os 3 pontos no `...["teste", "2"].`

Será que tem jeito?

Esse é o erro que está dando:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'a' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/gasmuriae.com.br/web/gceu/teste.php on line 10
```

Comment: Não entendi o ponto da pergunta. Quando vc define um parâmetro com `...` significa que o número de argumentos passados é variável pode ser 1,2,3, 10 etc.

Comment: pois é. Então parece que foi eu quem não entendeu muito bem. O objetivo é que esses pontos referenciassem um array ttipado de strings

Comment: Relaciondas: [Qual é o nome do operador … usado no PHP 5.6?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87234/91) e [Qual a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/91)

Comment: No php não existe generics o hack (aquela linguagem criado pelo facebook em cima do php) tem.

Comment: Ok, mas como seria o caso de eu ter que  passar um array de strings para a função como um dos argumentos pois  pois o segundo parâmto da função exija uma string por exemplo? Essa é a minha dificuldade.

Answer (score 1):

O que você precisa não é do *spread operator*, o `...`, então não há como utilizá-lo para fazer o que deseja.

O *spread operator* agrupa todos os parâmetros passados para função dentro de um *array*. Se utilizá-lo no primeiro parâmetro, significa que **todos** pertencerão ao *array*, por isso se definir um segundo parâmetro dará erro. Você pode ter outros parâmetros antes, mas não depois. Leia mais na documentação oficial [Número variável de argumentos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list).

O que você precisa é somente de dois parâmetros, sendo que um é do tipo *array*:

```
function my_push(array $arr, string $value): array {
    array_push($arr, $value);
    return $arr;
}

print_r(my_push(["teste","2"], "adicionado"));
```

Ficando:

```
Array
(
    [0] => teste
    [1] => 2
    [2] => adicionado
)
```

---

**Solução "*crianças não façam isso em casa*"**

Você possui um serrote e um martelo, precisando fixar um prego. Esta solução mostra como utilizar o serrote ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Ao inverter as posições dos parâmetros você consegue obter algo semelhante ao que deseja, porém é utilizar de forma errada o operador *spread*.

```
function my_push(string $value, string ...$arr): array {
    array_push($arr, $value);
    return $arr;
}

print_r(my_push('adicionado', ...[1, 2]));
```

Resultando:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => adicionado
)
```

Mas utilizando o operador *spread*, também permitirá fazer `my_push(1, 2, 3)`, produzindo o mesmo resultado. Leia somente esta chamada de função e me diga quem está sendo adicionado em quem? Péssimo para dar manutenção, não faça isso. Será só uma questão de tempo para arrepender-se - se trabalhar em equipe, esse tempo diminuirá significativamente.

Perceba que mesmo colocando o tipo *string* no parâmetro o PHP aceitou eu passar uma lista de inteiros. É PHP, ele faz isso. Ele te deixa passar uma lista de inteiros, mas fará o *casting* para *string*. Você passa uma lista de inteiros e recebe uma lista de *strings* - outra coisa que só complica a vida de quem está lendo o código.

Comment: sim, perfeito. Mas até eu já tinha conseguido em outros testes. O que estou precisando é dizer que esse array será tipado e SÓ poderá receber tipos STRING. Em um outro post,(https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/354586/array-espec%C3%ADfico-de-strings-em-php-%C3%A9-poss%C3%ADvel) lí que fazendo string ... $parâmetro resolveria. Mas quando entrei com um segundo parâmetro não funcionou. Pode me ajudar nessa situação?

Comment: adicionei dados à pergunta

Comment: Até tem como fazer algo parecido, mas é utilizar o operador de forma errada, então não vale a pena. Se precisa garantir que os valores sejam strings, faça um loop e valide todos.

Comment: sim, mas como ficaria no tipo que você falou:  (mas é utilizar o operador de forma errada)

Comment: hum, entendi. Mas...e se eu adicionar declare(strict_types=1); ao inicio do arquivo. Isso me garante a obrigação da tipagem. Não?

Comment: Sim, mas ainda permitiria `my_push('1', '2', '3')`, que não fica claro o que faz.